# When should a UITableViewCell with implicitly unwrapped optional register for notifications?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsnotificationcenter

A subclass of `UITableViewCell` adds observers to `NSNotificationCenter` in `awakeFromNib`. However the class also has an implicitly unwrapped optional as property.

```
class aCell: UITableViewCell() {

   var aProperty: Int!

   override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()

      NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(...)
   }

   func notificationReceived() {
      print(aProperty)
   }
}
```

But `awakeFromNib` is called before `aProperty` can be set:

```
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(...)
   cell.aProperty = 1
```

In the event of a notification before setting the property, the `notificationReceived` accesses `aProperty` while it is nil and the app crashes.

So where should the cell register itself for notifications if I don't want to manually call it as a method after setting the property?

Comment: Is it necessary to aProperty be non-optional? You can can make it optional if does not break your business logic. e.g. "var aProperty: Int?"

Comment: It's a matter of convenience so I don't have to always unwrap it.

Comment: In that case, 1.you can check if the property is nil in "notificationReceived" function, or 2. Set a initial value of that property.

Comment: What about the initializer ? Also, if you're supporting iOS 8 or earlier don't forget to call `removeObserver`

Comment: @deadbeef The cell is initialized via `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` because it is designed in IB so it always returns a cell.

Comment: @Manuel I know. And `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will call `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`, so you can override that.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to register for the notification as late as possible to avoid a crash is a bad idea because you will never do it late enough to be 100% sure.

It's better to just check that the value is not nil in your case

```
class aCell : UITableViewCell
{
    var aProperty: Int!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notificationReceived(_:)), name: "...", object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    func notificationReceived(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard let aProperty = self.aProperty else {
            return
        }
        print(aProperty)
    }
}
```

Comment: that I know, I guess I will have to use Optionals which is really a pain. Because I know the parameters will never be nil once I've set them. But I cannot use my own initializer because initializing is managed by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.